# Is it possible to support vertical typing in Android?

Tags: java, android

Hi,everyone
  As suggested in the title, what I'm trying to do is the following:

Normally, if you type something to screen, for instance "Horizontal", you will get

Horizontal, which is displayed horizontally.

But what I really want is like
   V
   e
   r
   t
   i
   c
   a
   l
   l
   y
also, every single letter rotated 90 degree clockwise(since I can't actually rotate them so just see them as rotated). I have been recommended doing this by using TextView and EditText, but I have no idea how do I get started. 
So can anybody help me out? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every View has a `setRotation(float)` method and a related XML attribute `android:rotation` since API level 11 as you can see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29

So you only have add the `android:rotation="90"` attribute to the TextView or EditText in your layout.